# For loop in batch file - fails when file names are given in double quotes

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I've a piece of code written in batch file which looks for a predefined file in  a use entered folder name. This works fine if the user doesn't enter the folder name in double quotes. But when he enters in double quotes, the for loop part in the batch file fails.

CODE:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=, skip=4" %%I IN (%A%\A.txt) DO ECHO %%I
```

When the value for A is given in double quotes it fails with error **The system cannot find the file F:\KnoB"\A.txt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you get the folder name from? If you get it from a command-line argument, then change your

```
set A=%1
```

to

```
set A=%~1
```

which removes the quotes, if present.

If you're reading from the user via `set /p` then use

```
set /P A=Folder?
for %%x in (%A%) do set A=%%~x
```

which does the same.

Generally, if you're getting the value from somewhere that uses only a single percent for variables (e.g. arguments or `for` loops), then just use the `~` in there.

You also want to surround the argument to your `for` loop in quotes, so that folder names with spaces don't cause unpleasant surprises:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=, skip=4" %%I IN ("%A%\A.txt") DO ECHO %%I
```

Comment: What will happen at this line: `for %%x in (%A%) do set A=%%~x` if `A` isn't enclosed in double quotes yet contains spaces?

Comment: Bad things, basically. It would really help if you could specify where the value comes from ...

Comment: Parsing user input in a batch file *with* the batch file has never been a trivial task, though attempts at solving it have been made, with more or less success. Still I maintain it's not the batch file's job (problem) to be overly fool-proof. Prompting the user about the correct input format (for example, in this case, always quoted, never quoted) should be enough. If a full-scale parsing is required, a different tool should be used. For this particular case, though, when it is assumed that the input is correct, but it's unknown whether it is quoted or not, I would use a subroutine.

Comment: Well, if it's unquoted and contains spaces this will essentially erase everything after the space. You could probably circumvent that by using `for /f "delims=" in ('echo.%A%') ...`

Comment: Nice trick with `echo`! Not sure what you mean by the erasing. I was talking about this: `call :dequote %A%; :dequote; if "%2"=="" (set A=%~1) else (set A=%*)` (`;` stands for 'new line'). Again, the assumption is that the path is correct, and it's simply unknown whether it's enclosed in double quotes.