# Using FOR loops to check file exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-prompt

I'm trying to use FOR loops to create a batch that checks if file exists in a directory. I'm struggling with files that has spaces with the file name and i don't want to have to use a .txt list if possible. So here is what i have tested so far.

```
@echo OFF
:: Variables
set Folder=D:\Test Folder
set Space=File Name With Space.txt
set NoSpace=FileNameWithoutSpace.txt

:: For Loop

FOR %%A in (%Space% %nospace%) do (
if exist "%Folder%\%%A" (
        ECHO %%A exist
        ) else (
            ECHO %%A doesn't exist
            echo. )
)
```

Here is what it reads when turned echo back on.

> (if exist "D:\Test Folder\File" (ECHO File exist )  else ( ECHO File
>   doesn't exist   echo.   ) )

And if i use this code:

```
@echo OFF    
:: Variables
set Folder=D:\Test Folder
set Space="File Name With Space.txt"
set NoSpace=FileNameWithoutSpace.txt

:: For Loop

FOR %%A in (%Space% %nospace%) do (

if exist "%Folder%\%%A" (
    ECHO %%A exist
    ) else (
        ECHO %%A doesn't exist
        echo. )
)
```

It reads the "IF" command as:

> (if exist "D:\Test Folder\"File Name With Space.txt"" (ECHO "File Name
>   With Space.txt" exist )  else ( ECHO "File Name With Space.txt"
>   doesn't exist    echo.   ) )

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `%~A` (read `set /?` or `cmd /?` for more details, I don't remember which)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310550/for-loop-in-batch-file-fails-when-file-names-are-given-in-double-quotes?rq=1)? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804782/5267751)?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, saying "thanks" is [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) on [so] (similar to Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron, this is the syntax you should be using, *(pay special attention to the placement of doublequotes, **`"`** and the use of the metavariable modifier, **`~`**):*

```bat
@Echo Off    
Rem Variables
Set "Folder=D:\Test Folder"
Set "Space=File Name With Space.txt"
Set "NoSpace=FileNameWithoutSpace.txt"

Rem For Loop
For %%A In ("%Space%" "%nospace%") Do (
    If Exist "%Folder%\%%~A" (
        Echo %%~A exists
    ) Else (
        Echo %%~A does not exist
        Echo=
    )
)
Pause
```

Comment: That works perfectly! The echo returns result with the doublequotes though. How do i get rid of that. Can you suggest reading material about the use of ~? I'd like to understand how that works too.  **_"File Name With Space.txt" exist_** is what i got.

Comment: I asked you to pay attention to the **`~`** metavariable modifier. Looking at the output from `For /?` when ran at the Command prompt would reveal, `%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")`. I've edited the code to match the request however.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
set Space=File Name With Space.txt
```

so

```
FOR %%A in (%Space% %nospace%) do (
```

translates to

```
FOR %%A in (File Name With Space.txt FileNameWithoutSpace.txt) do (
```

which searches for the following files:

```
File
Name
With
Space.txt
FileNameWithoutSpace.txt
```

Quote your arguments:

```
FOR %%A in ("%Space%" "%nospace%") do (
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it reads the "FOR" command correctly, but in the "IF" command it reads: (if exist "D:\Test Folder\"File Name With Space.txt"" (ECHO "File Name With Space.txt" exist )  else (
ECHO "File Name With Space.txt" doesn't exist).

Comment: `if exist "D:\Test Folder\"File Name With Space.txt""...`?? I think, you didn't understand the concept of quoting: `if exist "D:\Test Folder\File Name With Space.txt" ...`